# PHP : Error in Query (MySQL) near WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to Insert data from a form with the use of a query. The query ( below ) has a WHERE clause to pick a position from visitorsystem.position.

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO visitorsystem.employee(idNumber,name,surname,position,email)
                                 VALUES ('$idNumber','$name','$surname',SELECT positionid FROM visitorsystem.position WHERE position LIKE '%$position%','$email')";
```

When executed the following error is given. I have tried adding quotes and single quotes around the SELECT...WHERE clause with no luck. Any ideas if the problem is with the query itself or the SELECT...WHERE clause ?

> Error in query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '','fdsf',SELECT positionid FROM visitorsystem.position WHERE
>   position LIKE '%inf' at line 2

Comment: It seems, you have missed single quote in $name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection.

Second you should add all values to the select Statement:

```
query = "INSERT INTO visitorsystem.employee(idNumber,name,surname,position,email)
  SELECT $idNumber,'$name','$surname',positionid,'$email' FROM visitorsystem.position WHERE position LIKE '%$position%'";
```

Also you do not need singlequotes around `$idNumber`, because it is numeric

Answer (score 4):

Change your query to :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO visitorsystem.employee(idNumber,name,surname,position,email)
         SELECT '$idNumber','$name','$surname',positionid,'$email' FROM visitorsystem.position WHERE position LIKE '%$position%'";
```

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo, as i was writing this question, thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: You can remove the hine about the single quote